# How to detect a Windows event in Qt?

Tags: c++, c, qt

I am trying to build an app to detect Windows events, in particular events related to multimedia (playing video, playing audio and images).

For instance, if Windows Media Player is opened, the related event should be detected.

Comment: For Media player, events available are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912134.aspx) but as said by FIO (and AFAIK) there's no real general support to your needs. By the way, for what concerns handling win events, take a look at [QWidget::nativeEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#nativeEvent).

Comment: What if the user has selected AcmeMusicPlayer as his default app for audio files? Also, if the user drops a whole album on the media player, do you want events for each item? This is horribly underspec'ced (and a problem regardless of the exact requirements)

Comment: A friendly reminder to answerers, please do not feed such questions with answers. We only try to answer proper questions in the qt tag.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'events' for that.

You can detect the lauches of media players (by winapi ::FindWindow) or image viewers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do this with QT's built in functions alone. You'll have to use the Windows API. Depending on what you actually want to do this can get quite complicated.
If you just want to check if a certain application has been started yet, you could use the [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. I'd suggest to use a qt timer to create signals that you can use to check if the Window has opened yet.
`QTimer::singleShot(200, this, SLOT(checkForMediaPlayer()));`
Just add this to your QObject along with the checkForMediaPlayer member function that'll do whatever you want once the MediaPlayer has been detected.